# Detect mouseover an image in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, game-engine

I have an image:

```
newGameButton = pygame.image.load("images/newGameButton.png").convert_alpha()
```

I then display it on the screen:

```
screen.blit(newGameButton, (0,0))
```

How do I detect if the mouse is touching the image?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use [`Surface.get_rect`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#Surface.get_rect) to get a [`Rect`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) describing the bounds of your [`Surface`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html), then use [`.collidepoint()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#Rect.collidepoint) to check if the mouse cursor is inside this [`Rect`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html).

---

**Example:**

```
if newGameButton.get_rect().collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
    print "mouse is over 'newGameButton'"
```

Comment: And if you have more than one button or Surfaces, make it a list to be checked against everytime you move the cursor.

Answer (score 5):

I'm sure there are more pythonic ways to do this, but here is a simple example:

```py
button_x = 0
button_y = 0
newGameButton = pygame.image.load("images/newGameButton.png").convert_alpha()
x_len = newGameButton.get_width()
y_len = newGameButton.get_height()
mos_x, mos_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
if mos_x>button_x and (mos_x<button_x+x_len):
    x_inside = True
else: x_inside = False
if mos_y>button_y and (mos_y<button_y+y_len):
    y_inside = True
else: y_inside = False
if x_inside and y_inside:
    #Mouse is hovering over button
screen.blit(newGameButton, (button_x,button_y))
```

Read more on the [mouse in pygame](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html), as well as [surfaces in pygame](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html).

Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10888145/1393894) is an example closely related to this.

Comment: How would one detect if the mouse is hovering over something _while_ at the same time the mouse button is being held down?