# (Pygame) Problems with Mouseover Detection

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I've seen both of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11846032/detect-mouseover-an-image-in-pygame) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17935484/mouseover-in-pygame), and still haven't got mouseover detection working. I'm developing a simple start menu for a game I'm working on for a friend; there are two pieces of text, and they are supposed to turn blue when hovered over.

However, they only turn blue when I hover my mouse in the upper-left corner: I'm assuming my code is detecting the original (unblitted and unpositioned) surface which is in the upper left corner, and converting *that* into a rect, then checking for .collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()).

How do I make it detect the already blitted and positioned text?

Here's my code (or at least the part that's causing trouble):

```
font = pygame.font.Font(os.path.join('.', 'bin', 'NOVEMBER.TTF'), 26)
playText = font.render("Play", True, lightGray)
settingsText = font.render("Options", True, lightGray)
setDisplay.fill(darkGray)
playText_rect = playText.get_rect()
settingsText_rect = settingsText.get_rect()
```

Then later, in my main loop:

```
if settingsText_rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
        settingsText = font.render("Options", True, grayBlue)
        setDisplay.blit(settingsText, (rightBorder / 2 - settingsText.get_width() / 2 + 200, bottomBorder / 2 - settingsText.get_height() / 2 + 120))
    elif playText_rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
        playText = font.render("Play", True, grayBlue)
        setDisplay.blit(playText, (rightBorder / 2 - playText.get_width() / 2 - 200, bottomBorder / 2 - playText.get_height() / 2 + 120))
    else:
        playText = font.render("Play", True, lightGray)
        settingsText = font.render("Options", True, lightGray)
```

Oh, and I'm on Ubuntu if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you simply call `.get_rect()` on a `Surface`, the resulting `Rect` indeed has its `x` and `y` position set to `0`.

An easy way to fix this is to use `playText_rect` and `settingsText_rect` for blitting instead of calculating the position in the main loop.

```
# calculate the position once and but the rect at that position
playText_rect = playText.get_rect(topleft=(rightBorder / 2 - playText.get_width() / 2 - 200, bottomBorder / 2 - playText.get_height() / 2 + 120))
settingsText_rect = settingsText.get_rect(topleft=(rightBorder / 2 - settingsText.get_width() / 2 + 200, bottomBorder / 2 - settingsText.get_height() / 2 + 120))

...

# use the rect as position argument for blit
setDisplay.blit(settingsText, settingsText_rect)

...

setDisplay.blit(playText, playText_rect)
```

Comment: Haha, didn't realize it was that simple. Thanks!