# get_rect() over an image gets shifted in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to do a drag-and-drop mechanic in pygame and I'm being partly successful (thanks to answers to questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11846032/detect-mouseover-an-image-in-pygame) and tutorials like [this other one](http://inventwithpython.com/pygame/chapter2.html)). The mechanic I'm using goes as follows: I update in every loop the position of the image once the event of pressing the button is detected (and only if the mouse is over the image). To do so, I created a rectangle object by just calling image.get_rect(), but it seems that this rectangle is shifted, with the center of the image laying in the bottom right of the rectangle. I annex both the code an the result:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

FPS = 60
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()


def main():
    pygame.init()

    DS = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400), 0, 32)
    pygame.display.set_caption('Drag-n-drop that cat')

    WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
    BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
    catImg = pygame.image.load('cat.png') # I load the image
    catImgRectObj = catImg.get_rect() # I create the rect object
    catx = 200
    caty = 200
    catImgRectObj.center = [catx, caty]
    IsMousePressed = False

    while True:
        lastPos = catImgRectObj.center
        DS.fill(WHITE)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                IsMousePressed = True
            elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                IsMousePressed = False

        if IsMousePressed and isMouseOverObj(catImgRectObj):
            catImgRectObj.center = pygame.mouse.get_pos() #I update the center
        else:
            catImgRectObj.center = lastPos

        pygame.draw.rect(DS, BLACK, catImgRectObj) #draw the rect object
        DS.blit(catImg, catImgRectObj.center) #draw the cat.
        pygame.display.update()
        fpsClock.tick(FPS)


def isMouseOverObj(Obj):
    return Obj.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: The result]

Comment: The image of the cat can be found [here](https://inventwithpython.com/cat.png), it's downloaded from the [tutorial webpage](http://inventwithpython.com/pygame/chapter2.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
DS.blit(catImg, catImgRectObj)
```

instead of

```
DS.blit(catImg, catImgRectObj.center)
```

to draw the cat.

[image]

The `catImgRectObj` rect already describes where the cat image is, and if you use `catImgRectObj.center` to blit it on the screen, but shift its top left corner to the center of the desired area.

---

Also, I would use something like this:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

FPS = 60
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()

def main():
    pygame.init()

    DS = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400), 0, 32)
    pygame.display.set_caption('Drag-n-drop that cat')

    catImg = pygame.image.load('cat.png').convert_alpha()
    catMask = pygame.mask.from_surface(catImg)
    catImgRectObj = catImg.get_rect(center=(200, 200))
    IsMousePressed = False

    while True:

        DS.fill(pygame.color.THECOLORS['white'])
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and isMouseOverObj(catMask, catImgRectObj):
                IsMousePressed = True
            elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                IsMousePressed = False
            elif event.type == MOUSEMOTION and IsMousePressed:
                catImgRectObj.move_ip(event.rel)

        DS.blit(catImg, catImgRectObj)
        pygame.display.update()
        fpsClock.tick(FPS)


def isMouseOverObj(mask, rect):
    mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    rel_pos = (mouse_pos[0] - rect.left, mouse_pos[1] - rect.top)
    return rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos) and mask.get_at(rel_pos)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

to make the collision detection pixel perfect, simplify the code a bit, and to prevent the *jumping* once you click on the cat.

Comment: you wouldn't believe how helpful that was, many thanks. By the way, what's the philosophy behind the mask object, what is it exactly?

Comment: It's basically a 2d array telling you if a particular pixel/point of the surface is actually filled or empty (transparent) space. Imagine it's some kind of copy of you surface, but only with 2 colors: black and white.

Comment: So, the mask.get_at(position) returns True if I'm over a "black" pixel?