# How to only get a key entry once per second? (or delay the time in between two keyboard entry)

Tags: python-2.7, pygame, keyboard-events

In pygame, I am using function "pressed_key"

This is my Code:

```
if(pressed_keys[K_y]):
    base += 10;
```

But when I do it by pressing it only once, the "base" increased 200ish. I want to know if there is a way to increase the time between two entry?

Thanks for helping!

(p.s. I really dont know how to search similar questions on this question. I hope this is not duplicate. But in case it is, let me know. I will delete this question. Thanks again!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you know enough about pygame to use a [clock](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock).

(For simplicity's sake we'll say the time interval required will be one second)

A simple solution would be to only check for input every second, using a simple counter and the pygame clock.

First off start the clock and the counter, *outside of your main loop*.
Also, add a boolean variable to determine if the key was pressed within this second.

```
FRAMERATE = 30 #(The framerate used in this example is 30 FPS)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
counter = 0
not_pressed = True
```

Then inside the main loop, the first thing you do is increase the counter, then [tick the clock](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#Clock.tick).

```
while argument:
    counter+=1
    clock.tick(FRAMERATE)
```

Then were you have your code, an `if` statement to see if the button has been pressed this second:

```
if not_pressed:
    if(pressed_keys[K_y]):
        not_pressed=False
        base += 10
#Rest of code:
if(pressed_keys[K_up]):
```

Finally, at the end of your main loop, add a checker to switch the boolean `not_pressed` back to True every second:

```
if counter == FRAMERATE:
    counter=0
    not_pressed=True
```

That should allow the program to only take input from the user once every second.
To change the interval, simply change the `if counter == FRAMERATE:` line.

- `if counter == FRAMERATE:` would be 1 Second
- `if counter == (FRAMERATE*2):` would be 2 Seconds
- `if counter == int(FRAMERATE/4):` would be a quarter of a second*

*note- make sure you turn `FRAMERATE` divided by a number, into an integer, either by using `int()` surrounding the division, or by using integer division: `(FRAMERATE//4)`

For a similar example to see how everything fits, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10888145/1393894).

Comment: well, the problem right now is actually more complicated. Right now I need the upper, down, left, right keys are repeat disabled but only "y" key would able the repeat function. Is that possible, bcz y is like accept something on buying, but other keys are for moving. Thanks so much!

Comment: @windsound as long as you have the `if` statements for the other keys outside of the `if not_pressed`, they will react whenever you press them. You can change `not_pressed` to `y_not_pressed` as well if you like.

Comment: @hammythebig that make sense but the problem right now is my other keys are not working. I cant move my character now. Do you have other way to chat, I want to know more about clock.tick function. Thanks so much!

Comment: @windsound sure we can chat in the [se python chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python)

Comment: @windsound also, I have edited my post to show where the other 'key pressed' checks would go. Make sure they are **NOT** indented with the `if not_pressed:`. And to learn more about clock.tick [read here](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#Clock.tick)

Answer (score 2):

Here http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.set_repeat

```
pygame.key.set_repeat(delay, interval): return None
```

also:

```
pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_y]: return bool
```

another way is to get the time you accepted the "key pressing" ,and wait before accepting it again:

```
import time
interval = 100 #you set your interval in miliseconds
lasttime = 0

while 1:
    draw() #draw routine
    events() #another events
    now = time.time() #save in one variable if you are going to test against more than one, reducing the number of time.time() calls
    if(pressed_keys[K_y] and (now-lasttime)>interval):
        lasttime = now
        base += 10
```

time.time() Return the time in seconds since the epoch as a floating point number. 
The epoch is the point where the time starts. On January 1st of that year, at 0 hours, the “time since the epoch” is zero. For Unix, the epoch is 1970.

knowing that, you are getting the time right now against the lasttime you saved it:
now-lasttime.
 When this delta is more than the interval, you are allowed to continue your event, don't forget to update your lasttime variable.

Comment: well, the problem right now is actually more complicated. Right now I need the upper, down, left, right keys are repeat disabled but only "y" key would able the repeat function. Is that possible, bcz y is like accept something on buying, but other keys are for moving. Thanks so much!

Comment: make it a "for" with the keys in a list: "for key in [K_UP,K_LEFT,K_DOWN,K_RIGHT]: if pressed_keys[key]: #code", you can also include another list with callbacks (functions to be called when "if" is True) "for key,func in zip(key_list,func_list): if pressed_keys[key]: func() #call the corresponding function", funclist is [func_up,func_left...] with is "def func_up(): #code"
search the "zip" syntax into python docs.

Answer (score 0):

See also: [Pygame: key.get_pressed() does not coincide with the event queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11910410/pygame-key-get-pressed-does-not-coincide-with-the-event-queue/11918084#11918084) To use repeated movement while key is held down. Using state polling for those keys works better.