# Pygame Buttons and Text

Tags: python, pygame

Does anyone know how to create buttons using pygame? I'm new to this sort of thing and am also creating a game, but how do you make buttons in the main window (1 window total) in pygame? Also, how do you display text? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## demo

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10892583/341744 It creates menu buttons, that change text color on hover.

> Take a look at this example menu :
>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/10747990/341744  specifically at his code:
>   https://gist.github.com/2802185
>
> It creates a class `Option`, which changes color when you mouseover.
>   You could extend it, so on click, the button calls a function. ( ie:
>   `new_game()` , `show_options()` etc )

## pygame project: Tags

And view the project examples via tags: 
[menu](http://www.pygame.org/tags/menu), 
[button](http://www.pygame.org/tags/button), 
[text](http://www.pygame.org/tags/text).